# Pex pipe to garden: Best way to connect to hose bib at house

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pex, copper-pipe

I want to connect a 150-200' run of pex from my house hose bib out to the garden.  I should probably take the hose bib off and attach another device to the copper so I can keep the hose bib and supply the water line to the garden.

What is that valve?
Thank you.

Comment: There are "pex" hose bibs available. Why won't this work for you?

Comment: There should be a pex to GHT fitting.  The type will depend if it is a one time attachment or needs to to be taken off often.

Comment: @gnicko I want to retain the garden hose bib, and send water to the outside line to the garden.

Comment: @crip659 This doesn't get me both hose bib and water to the line to garden.  Thank you for your comment.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Pick a material other than PEX. PEX is not intended for use outdoors in direct sunlight. The UV rays in sunlight cause it to break down. If you Google "PEX outdoors" you will find 12 million reasons not to use PEX outdoors. Admittedly, some of the 12 million are duplicates, but you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the caution.  I will be burying it so I should be good, but I certainly won't be using pex for the uprights. now.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the 200 feet distance, you might experience slow flow depending on the pipe size.

If you can, consider using 3/4 inch (or larger) pipe, not 1/2 inch.

You can find the adapters for that in your hardware store.

A splitter will look like this Just a example not a recommendation of the source)

[image: splitter]

Comment: As I mentioned above in my comments, I want to have a hose bib and water to the outside line.  I think I will use the 3/4, but I need that valve (?) that outputs both.

Comment: @Terrence see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you @Ruskes.